# PHP, MySQL, categories, and subcategories – the deletion

Tags: php, mysql, categories, cascading-deletes

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Parent INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) Engine=InnoDB
```

I'd like to ensure the deletion of all children whenever a parent gets deleted. At first, I wanted to do it by adding a foreign key like that to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE categories ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY Parent(Parent) 
REFERENCES categories(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This doesn't work. I've also tried internal relations, but without success.

Parents and their children are linked with a recursive PHP function. Is there a way in MySQL to achieve the goal, or it should be done using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

```
#Server version: 5.1.42-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)
create table lists(
   id int not null
  ,parent int
  ,primary key(id)
  ,foreign key(parent) references lists(id) on delete cascade
) Engine=InnoDb;

insert into lists(id, parent) values(1, null);
insert into lists(id, parent) values(2, 1);
insert into lists(id, parent) values(3, 2);
insert into lists(id, parent) values(4, 3);

mysql> select * from lists;
+----+--------+
| id | parent |
+----+--------+
|  1 |   NULL |
|  2 |      1 |
|  3 |      2 |
|  4 |      3 |
+----+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> delete from lists where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql>
mysql> select * from lists;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the Foreign Key the other way around.
You should Define it as:

```
ALTER TABLE categories ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES Parent(Parent) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
drop table if exists categories;
create table categories
(
cat_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
name varchar(255) not null,
parent_id int unsigned null,
foreign key (parent_id) references categories(cat_id) on delete cascade
)
engine = innodb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ronnis, Foo, you're right. It really works. :-)

The thing I was doing wrong was putting "0" for the first parent via my PHP application. Of course, if I put "0" (there's no parent with the id "0"), then I'm violating the foreign key rules. So, all I had to do was to edit my INSERT statement a little bit. Thank you a lot for bringing this to my attention. Thanks everybody!